# Django queryset - filter/exclude by sum over column

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

For a small caching application I have the following problem/question:

Part of the model:

```
class CachedResource(models.Model):
    ...
    filesize = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    ...
```

The cache should be e.g. limited to 200MB - and keep the newest files.

How can I create a queryset like:

```
CachedResource.objects.order_by('-created').exclude(" summary of filesize < x ")
```

Any input appreciated!

Example:

```
created             filesize        keep/delete?

2014-06-22 15:00          50        keep    (sum: 50)
2014-06-22 14:50         100        keep    (sum: 150)
2014-06-22 14:40          30        keep    (sum: 180)
2014-06-22 14:30          20        keep    (sum: 200)
2014-06-22 14:20          50        delete  (sum: 250 > 200)
2014-06-22 14:10          10        delete  ...
2014-06-22 14:00         200        delete  ...
2014-06-22 13:50          10        delete  ...
2014-06-22 13:40           2        delete  ...
             ...         ...        ...     ...
```

Comment: How important is it that the exact cumulative filesize is 200MB (or 1TB)? Wouldn't an approximation suffice?

Comment: Yes - completely. Say +/- 20% ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object in the following queryset will have a 'filesize_sum' attribute holding the summary of filesizes of all cache resources created since that object's creation time.

```
qs = CachedResource.objects.order_by('-created').extra(select={
  'filesize_sum': """
   SELECT
     SUM(filesize)
   FROM
     CachedResource_table_name as cr
   WHERE
     cr.created >= CachedResource_table_name.created
     """})
```

Then you can make a loop to do what you want. For example, you could make a loop that breaks on the first object with filesize_sum > 200MB and run a delete query on the queryset for all objects with a smaller or equal creation date to that object:

```
for obj in qs:
   if obj.filesize_sum > 200:
       qs.filter(created__lte=obj.created).delete()
       break
```

Keep in mind though that you probably want to also take some action before inserting a new cache resource, so that the filesize of the new resource does not exceed your limit. For example, you could run the above procedure with:

`limit = configured_limit - filesize_of_cache_resource_to_insert`

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a better way to do that:

```
cachedResources = CachedResource.objects.order_by('-created')
list_of_items = []
size_of_files = 0
for item in cachedResources:
    if size_of_files < 200:
        list_of_items.append(item.id)
    else
        break
cached_resources_by_size = CachedResource.objects.filter(id__in=list_of_items).order_by('-created')
```

Comment: :) Yes this something that I would hack together as well if there is no other solution... But it is highly inefficient. Think not having 200MB as the limit but 1TB - and files of ~1kb size...

Comment: You are right, that can be a problem... I will think about better solution

Answer (score 0):

```
totals = CachedResource.objects.values('id').aggregate(sum=Sum('filesize'), count=Count('id'))
num_to_keep = totals['count'] * min(MAX_FILESIZE / totals['sum'], 1)
while num_to_keep < totals['count']:
    new_sum = CachedResource.objects.filter(id__in=CachedResource.objects.order_by('-created')[:num_to_keep]).aggregate(sum=Sum('filesize'))
    # if <not acceptable approximation>:
    #    adjust approximation
    #    continue

    CachedResource.objects.order_by('-created')[num_to_keep:].delete()
    break
```

The aggregation in line 1 can get you the total filesize and the number of entries in a single query. Based on these results, it's easy to calculate an approximated amount of entries to keep. You can do some extra checking to assert that this approximation falls within certain limits (+/- 20% as you said). Then a simple `order_by` and a slice will result in a queryset of all entries to delete.